# Rekeying a Schlage Connect smart lock

Tags: deadbolt

So my wife finally gave me permission to go ahead and buy a smart lock to add to the rest of our growing smart home gadgets. I'm looking at the Schlage Connect. We currently have a separate deadbolt and doorknob, both with locks that use the same key. They have "Dexter by Schlage" branding on them.

My question is- if I replace the deadbolt with the Schlage Connect and the doorknob itself with a non-locking options (else you could lock yourself out if that one gets locked and you depend upon the keypad to get in!), can I replace the pins in the Schlage Connect with those from the previous deadbolt so I can continue to use the same key?

Comment: Don't rely on electronics for access to your home. Stash a key nearby, and keep the locking knob for occasional convenience.

Comment: I'd be relying on electronics for 'convenient' access to the home. It's still a proper deadbolt with a physical metal key, it just also has a touchpad a vistor/guest with the proper code can use to get inside. It's really not much different than the exterior keypad to open the garage door nearly everyone I know has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

You may even be able to save yourself some trouble by just swapping the deadbolt core (the small tube that holds the pins). When I first bought my house, I went around and re-keyed all the locks to the same key. I believe as long as the lock is the same brand, it's possible to re-key.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Glfj_DYOkcU) is a video showing the removal of the core and re-keying it. If you need to rekey a lock and you don't have the pins for some reason, you can buy a [Schlage re-keying set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002N768).

Comment: Turns out it was easy. $10 and 5 minutes later, a local locksmith rekeyed the new deadbolt to use my existing key.

Comment: Congrats, that is much cheaper than I would have expected.